# Series solution for $y'+(1-2x)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, taylor-expansion, power-series

> $y'+(1-2x)y=0$

I'm not interested in the recurrence formula. I just want the first three terms of non-zero terms.
By the integrating factor method, I've found $y(x)=Ce^{x^2-x}$ is the general solution. I'm asked to provide the first three non-zero terms of Taylor series for this solution, and that of power series method, and then compare. If I'm not wrong, the first three terms of this integrating factor method are $C, -Cx$, and $3Cx^2$. So I should obtain the equivalent three terms for the alternative method, namely power series method.

Here's my attempt so far:

Assume $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is a power series solution for this ODE. Then we have $y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$. Substituting these in the ODE, we have

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}+(1-2x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=0$
>
> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+1}=0$

Shifting the dummy variables (remaining the sum in the middle the same), we have

> $\sum_{m=0}^\infty (m+1)a_{m+1}x^m+\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m-2\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{m-1}x^m=0$

Arranging some terms,

> $a_1+a_0+\sum_{m=1}^\infty [(m+1)a_{m+1}+a_{m}-2a_{m-1}]x^m=0$

So, we have $a_1=-a_0$ and $a_{m+1}=\frac{2a_{m-1}-a_m}{m+1}$ for $m\geq 1$

However, I noticed the first three terms obtained from this approach are not equivalent to the one obtained before, $C,-Cx,$ and $3Cx^2$. Am I wrong? If so, where? I'm terribly confused.

Comment: In the first method you should get $C, -Cx$, and $(3/2) Cx^2$ and there is no conflict with the second method.

Comment: @geetha290krm Wait, ah I forgot the denominator of Taylor expansion, that is $1/2!$ in the integrating factor one, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.